# Auto detecting serial COM port from VendorID, ProductID in Java

Tags: java, serial-port, usb

I have a program in java 11, control some hardware through USB using serial COM port.
I want to auto-detect hardware by **VenderID** and **ProductID** whenever I plug in a device.

I can get VendorID and ProductID through Linux command:

`udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyACM0`

```
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-5':
    KERNELS=="1-5"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ...
    ...
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0c2e"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0bea"
    ...
```

Is it any way to get a COM port `/dev/ttyACM0` from VendorID and ProductID with Java 11 in Linux and Windows?
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USB abstraction library [libusbp](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/) comes with an example program named [lsport](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/blob/master/examples/lsport/lsport.cpp) that lists all USB device and the serial ports they have.  You could compile that program and run it from your Java program, or just study how it works and reimplement the same thing in Java.

For Linux, another idea is to look at the symbolic links in `/dev/serial/by-id`.

Comment: Hello David,
Thank you for your help, It works right now!